# How upload a image in other directory outside of WebApp in ckeditor grails plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, ckeditor

I am trying to use CKEditor plugin for Grails to let users upload and insert images. I have a couple of issues:

1. Security: I want to allow users to upload images and keep them private so other users can not access them. Can I define subdirectories where to upload the images using ckeditor plugin?
2. After uploading an image (to a common directory), I get a 404 error when I try to retrieve the image. Images are saved to the dir pointed by 'baseDir' configuration setting. If I store images within the 'webapps' directory, I can retrieve them, but not when I use a different directory, outside of my webapp.

My configuration looks like this:

```
ckeditor {
config = "/js/ckconfig.js"
skipAllowedItemsCheck = false
defaultFileBrowser = "ofm"
upload {
    baseurl = "/ck"
    basedir = "c://Users//jose//project//ck//"
    overwrite = false
    link {
        browser = true
        upload = false
        allowed = []
        denied = ['html', 'htm', 'php', 'php2', 'php3', 'php4', 'php5',
                  'phtml', 'pwml', 'inc', 'asp', 'aspx', 'ascx', 'jsp',
                  'cfm', 'cfc', 'pl', 'bat', 'exe', 'com', 'dll', 'vbs', 'js', 'reg',
                  'cgi', 'htaccess', 'asis', 'sh', 'shtml', 'shtm', 'phtm']
    }
    image {
        browser = true
        upload = true
        allowed = ['jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png']
        denied = []
    }
    flash {
        browser = false
        upload = false
        allowed = ['swf']
        denied = []
    }
}
}
```

Has anyone been able to solve this?

Thanks